# Bulk Edit Option in Media

Tags: wordpress

```
add_action('init', 'theme_register_tax');
function theme_register_tax() {
   register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'attachment');
   add_post_type_support('attachment', 'category');
}
```

By the above, we can give category rights to the media files or attachments also, but for posts, WordPress is packed with a default bulk edit for posts →[image]

Is there a possibility that we can pass on this to the `'media'` post types also?